# Invalidate a custom view from activity

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am trying to redraw my custom view when a menu button is clicked. I know that invalidate forces the onDraw to be called again but this doesn't seem to be working.

Here some of my code, there is 400+ lines so i just cut it down to what i think is important.

```
public class Project2Activity extends Activity {
    private DrawViewProject2 dvp2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new DrawViewProject2(this));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.project2, menu);
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.new_game:

                    newGame();
                    break;
            case R.id.game_stats:

                    gameStats();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
    }

    public void newGame(){
            randomPosition = 0;
            randomValue = 0;
            xLocationForX.clear();
            yLocationForX.clear();
            xLocationForO.clear();
            yLocationForO.clear();
            winCheck = false;
            tieCount = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
                    squares[i] = 0;
            }

            dvp2 = new DrawViewProject2(getApplicationContext());

            /**** THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO INVALIDATE IT ****/
            dvp2.invalidate();
    }

    class DrawViewProject2 extends View implements OnTouchListener{
            /**
            * Constructor method.
            * @param context
            */
            public DrawViewProject2(Context context){
                    super(context);
                    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
                    // Set application background color.
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(0, 139, 103));

                    // Set Square color and draw squares.
                    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 220, 0));
                    drawAllSquares(15, 15, 251, 251, canvas);


                    xReDrawAll(canvas);
                    oReDrawAll(canvas);
                // ....some code here
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // .... some code here
                    return true;
            }

            /**
            * Used for Re drawing all X's and adding a new X
            * using the x and y coordinates.
            * @param x
            * @param y
            * @param canvas
            */
            public void xReDrawAll(float x, float y, Canvas canvas){
                    //Holds past X coordinates and redraws them all.
                    xLocationForX.add(x);
                    yLocationForX.add(y);
                    for(int i = 0, e = 0; i <xLocationForX.size(); i++){
                            //X shape for x player
                            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                            paint.setTextSize(300f);
                            canvas.drawText("X", xLocationForX.get(i), yLocationForX.get(i), paint);
                    }
            }
            /**
            * Used for Re drawing all O's
            * @param canvas
            */
            public void xReDrawAll(Canvas canvas){
                    for(int i = 0, e = 0; i <xLocationForX.size(); i++){
                            //X shape for x player
                            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                            paint.setTextSize(300f);
                            canvas.drawText("X", xLocationForX.get(i), yLocationForX.get(i), paint);
                    }
            }
            // .... lot more code down here.
```

I have also tried postInvalidate as well, that didn't do anything either.

My application works fine, i just need it to Re Draw when someone clicks on new game in the menu.

Comment: how do you know that it is not re-drawing? Maybe its re-drawing but since nothing changed.. you cannot make a difference.. plaese clarify if you change something.. and if you do.. post the code snippet for that part..

Comment: Run Debug with a break point at `dvp2.invalidate();` and follow the program flow from that point onward.  Does it get to reach that line? Does your onDraw execute as expected?

Comment: I posted some more code in the newGame(), onDraw(), and two methods on the bottom of the code. I have a basic tic tak toe game, and im simply attepmting to clear the X's and O's off the screen but redraw everything else.

Comment: @SoundConception I ran debug but i've never really used it before. i put the break point at that like but im not really sure what i should be looking for.

Comment: It's definitely worth getting to know debug. Did your app stop at that line when you ran debug? If not, then you know that the call to invalidate isn't being reached when you run. If the line is being reached then try putting a break point in your onDraw() and run debug again. When it stops in onDraw() this time, you can continue executing the code 1 line at a time with the step buttons, and inspect the values of your variables to make sure it does what you expect. You can also use the resume button to contine execution as normal until another break point is reached.

Comment: @SoundConception So when i have my breakpoint at the dvp2.invalidate(); line it stops when i hit newGame. but when i have the breakpoint at onDraw() it doesn't stop when i hit new game. does that mean that somehow invalidate IS being reached but it's NOT calling onDraw() ??

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to reset my past point.x and point.y coordinates and even though i was reseting everything else. it was still using those to redraw what i had.

Comment: Cool. Glad it's solved. I'd still recommend getting to know debug though. It's saved me from pulling my hair out a few times.